# How do u position the title in a error message box? java

Tags: java

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Select another","Not Allowed",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

to the left

Comment: You don't, it's typically positioned by the native OS's and it's own requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be positioned in a simple way. You can draw the dialog box yourself if you really want to but it is not recommended just for displaying an error message.

The layout of the dialog box is determined by the operating system that you are using. For example, in Windows 7, the title aligns to the left. In Windows 8, the title is centered. You can do nothing about it.

Also, the look and feel of the dialog boxes should vary from OS to OS. Imagine what the user sees when he is using Windows 8 but your dialog is aligned to the left. He will probably think that this is a bug or something.

Comment: If you think this solves your problem, please click on the tick below the votes to accept my answer! @Jets